# BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor - How to register a @Configuration class as BeanDefinition and get its @Beans registered as well

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-bean

Let's suppose I have this `@Configuration` class:

```
@Configuration
public class SomeConfig{

    @Bean
    public MyBean myBean(){
         return new MyBean();
    } 

    @Bean
    public Another anotherBean(){
         return new AnotherBean();
    }
}
```

I have a class that implements `BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor` to add certain `BeanDefinition`s. On it I also would like to import `SomeConfig` so that its beans are added to the context:

```
@Override
public void postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(BeanDefinitionRegistry registry) throws BeansException {
    BeanDefinition someConfig= new RootBeanDefinition("x.y.z.SomeConfig");
    registry.registerBeanDefinition("someConfig", someConfig);
}
```

The problem is that `SomeConfig`'s beans (`myBean`, `anotherBean`) haven't been added to the context. There is a someConfig bean though:

```
@Autowired
MyBean myBean   ---> FAILS

@Autowired
AnotherBean anotherBean   ---> FAILS

@Autowired
SomeConfig someConfig   ---> OK
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There reason why it didn't import the `@Bean`s was that `ConfigurationClassPostProcessor` was executed before my postprocessor so the new beans weren't added. To solve it I implemented `PriorityOrdered`:

```
@Configuration
public class MyFactoryPostProcessor implements BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor, PriorityOrdered{

    @Override
    public void postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(BeanDefinitionRegistry registry) throws BeansException {
        BeanDefinition someConfig= new RootBeanDefinition("x.y.z.SomeConfig");
        registry.registerBeanDefinition("someConfig", someConfig);
    }

    @Override
    public int getOrder() {
        return Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE;
    }
}
```

It's also **important** that the postprocessor class is `@Configuration` and is **imported directly in the config**, not defined in another `@Configuration` class with it defined as @Bean:

```
@Configuration
public class BeanDefinitionFactoryTestConfig {

    @Bean
    public MyFactoryPostProcessor cc(){
        return new MyFactoryPostProcessor ();
    }   
}
```

**`-->> THIS WILL FAIL TO IMPORT THE BEANS<<--`**

Comment: hi ,I follow this answer and use 'PriorityOrdered', but I still cannot get beans defined in @Configuration config class, can u please show me the full code ?many thanks!

Comment: Where is this mentioned in spring documentation?

Comment: I tried several approaches for this, tried BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor as well but could get it working coz I was creating @Bean out of it. Thanks a lot for this answer. You just saved my day.