# Spring Boot Factory Bean Creation Order

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-starter

I am trying to dynamically register Beans in Spring Boot, however the order of how the beans are created always result in a `NoSuchBeanDefinitionException` if it try to autowire one of the dynamic beans.

My setup consists of two projects, one spring-boot-starter project and the actual spring-boot application.

The actual application registers a `BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor` that adds the bean definitions. The instances itself are constructed via another bean defined in the starter project that itself takes another bean as dependency.

In order to consume the dynamically registered bean, I created a class annotated with `@Component` and defined a constructor expecting said bean as parameter.
When I debug the application by setting `@Autowired(required=false)`, I can see that the constructor of my component is called before the dynamic bean has been created. Moreover, not even the factory bean has been created at that time.

Added `@DependsOn` with the factory bean's name to component resulted the factory being created first, but not the dynamic beans.

Setting `@DependsOn` with the dynamic bean's name works, but that doesn't seem to be the correct way to solve this issue.

Why is Spring creating my beans in the wrong order and what can I do solve this?

**EDIT:**

I was able to reproduce the issue in a sample repository:
https://github.com/maveeee/spring-dynamic-bean-demo/

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`@Order`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/annotation/Order.html) annotation which  defines the sort order for an annotated component or bean.

Take into account that before Spring 4.0, this annotation was used only for the AspectJ execution order. After Spring 4.0, it is supported the ordering of injected components to a collection. Thus, Spring will inject the auto-wired beans of the same type based on their order value.

For example:

```
interface IBean {
    String getName();
}

public class BeanX implements IBean {
    public BeanX() {}

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "BeanX";
    }
}

public class BeanY implements IBean {
    public BeanY() {}

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "BeanY";
    }
}

@Component
public class RandomComponent {
    @Autowired
    private List<IBean> beans;

    @PostConstruct
    public void getBeanValues() {
        System.out.println("\n---@Bean---\n");
        for (IBean b : beans) {
            System.out.println(b.getName());
        }
    }

    @Bean
    @Order(1)
    public IBean getBeanX() {
        return new BeanX();
    }

    @Bean
    @Order(0)
    public IBean getBeanY() {
        return new BeanY();
    }
}
```

Will print:

```
---@Bean---

BeanY
BeanX
```

Because `BeanY` has higher precedence (`0`, lower value) over `BeanX` (higher value, `1`).

[GitHub Demo](https://github.com/lealceldeiro/order-demo)

Related articles:

- [@Order in Spring](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-order)
- [What is the use of @Order annotation in Spring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30328897/what-is-the-use-of-order-annotation-in-spring)
- [Spring annotation @Order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49292648/spring-annotation-order)
- [Order of Configuration in SpringBoot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44314418/order-of-configuration-in-springboot)

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I tried using `@Order` as well as implementing `PriorityOrdered` neither had the expected outcome.

Comment: @MaVe do you have a demo repo in which I can take a look at?

Comment: I will extract the relevant parts and setup a demo repository

Comment: thank you for all the effort you put into your answer! I tried extracting the relevant parts into a separate project as I cannot provide the whole code base in which my issue occurs. Unfortunately, I was not able to reproduce the issue. The original code uses 3 different spring boot starter, two of them I control myself and one is third party. Maybe I oversimplified things in my demo project. I will continue trying to reproduce the issue...

Comment: @MaVe you're welcome :) If you finally are able to reproduce the issue do not hesitate, drop me a comment here and I'll try to help you.

Comment: I could finally reproduce the issue: A sample can be seen at https://github.com/maveeee/spring-dynamic-bean-demo/

Comment: @MaVe when you get a chance check this [pull request](https://github.com/maveeee/spring-dynamic-bean-demo/pull/1) in order to see if that solves you problem and let me know if it solved the problem so I can update the answer for future readers.

Comment: Thank you for your pull request, unfortunately it does not solve my problem. The `BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor` you added registers the beans in a similar fashion, however, I need to create them through a factory bean which itself has autowired properties. The way I created the beans in `DynamicBeanGenerator` is just an oversimplification of what I am doing in my project. In reality a more complex data structure is passed to the factory instead of just the `Class<?>` object.
So unfortunately my problem still exists, however, it seems that the issue is related to using a factory bean

Comment: @MaVe yes, indeed! Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41444078/5640649

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that my issue resulted from how I created the bean definition. I was using a `GenericBeanDefinition` instead of a `RootBeanDefinition`. Using the later allowed me to use `setTargetType()` instead of `setBeanClass()` which immediately resolved the issue and resulted in Spring figuring out the correct order to create the beans so that I could inject the dynamically created bean via `@Autowired`.

Before:

```
        var identifier = ...    // Some String identifying the bean
        var clazz = ...         // Some class object coming from a dependency

        var beanDefinition = new GenericBeanDefinition();
        beanDefinition.setBeanClass(clazz);
        beanDefinition.setScope(BeanDefinition.SCOPE_SINGLETON);
        beanDefinition.setAutowireCandidate(true);
        beanDefinition.setFactoryBeanName(CONTRACT_FACTORY_BEAN_NAME);
        beanDefinition.setFactoryMethodName(CONTRACT_FACTORY_METHOD_NAME);

        registry.registerBeanDefinition(identifier, beanDefinition);
```

After:

```
        var identifier = ...    // Some String identifying the bean
        var clazz = ...         // Some class object coming from a dependency

        var beanDefinition = new RootBeanDefinition();
        beanDefinition.setTargetType(clazz);
        beanDefinition.setScope(BeanDefinition.SCOPE_SINGLETON);
        beanDefinition.setAutowireCandidate(true);
        beanDefinition.setFactoryBeanName(CONTRACT_FACTORY_BEAN_NAME);
        beanDefinition.setFactoryMethodName(CONTRACT_FACTORY_METHOD_NAME);

        registry.registerBeanDefinition(identifier, beanDefinition);
```

I will update the sample code in the [repository](https://github.com/maveeee/spring-dynamic-bean-demo/) for further reference.